# ¿Como puedo obtener la mascara de subred (netmask) de tu ip local?

Tags: c#

Tengo esta funcion que me permite saber cual es mi mascara de red de la red en la que estoy conectada. El problema es que me deberia aparecer `255.255.255.0` por la red donde estoy pero me aparece esta mascara `255.255.192.0`, supongo que algo esta mal en mi funcion pero no detecto que puede ser.

Esta es la función:

```
public static class SubnetMask
    {
        public static readonly IPAddress ClassA = IPAddress.Parse("255.0.0.0");
        public static readonly IPAddress ClassB = IPAddress.Parse("255.255.0.0");
        public static readonly IPAddress ClassC = IPAddress.Parse("255.255.255.0");

        public static IPAddress CreateByHostBitLength(int hostpartLength)
        {
            int hostPartLength = hostpartLength;
            int netPartLength = 32 - hostPartLength;

            if (netPartLength < 2)
                throw new ArgumentException("Number of hosts is to large for IPv4");

            Byte[] binaryMask = new byte[4];

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                if (i * 8 + 8 <= netPartLength)
                    binaryMask[i] = (byte)255;
                else if (i * 8 > netPartLength)
                    binaryMask[i] = (byte)0;
                else
                {
                    int oneLength = netPartLength - i * 8;
                    string binaryDigit =
                        String.Empty.PadLeft(oneLength, '1').PadRight(8, '0');
                    binaryMask[i] = Convert.ToByte(binaryDigit, 2);
                }
            }
            return new IPAddress(binaryMask);
        }


    }
```

Comment: La función luce bien. ¿Qué valor le estás pasando como argumento en la llamada?

Comment: mi IP de la maquina 
 string submask = SubnetMask.CreateByHostBitLength(myIP.Length).ToString();

Comment: Bueno, todo depende de qué myIP.Length tenga el valor correcto. Si tu máscara de red es de 24 bits, como indicas en la pregunta, esto debiera devolver 8. Si no tiene ese valor, revisa esa parte. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tengo una solución alternativa:

Adiciona estos using:

```
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Linq;
```

Y llama a esta función/método sin parámetros:

```
public static string GetSubnetMask()
{
    string result = string.Empty;

    NetworkInterface adapter = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces().Where(i => i.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet).FirstOrDefault();
    UnicastIPAddressInformation unicast = adapter.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses.Where(u => u.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork).FirstOrDefault();

    result = unicast.IPv4Mask.ToString();

    return result;
}
```

Esta función obtiene la máscara de red directamente de la tarjeta y no realiza el cálculo como lo hace tu función.

Para utilizarla copia la función en tu clase SubnetMask simplemente haces la llamada:

```
string submask = SubnetMask.GetSubnetMask();
```

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda @jtaborga, si me sirvio